# How do I properly load jQuery & Bootstrap into Joomla?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I'm building a form that uses jquery and bootstrap in the backend of joomla, however I get an error.

Here is the joomla code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<?php
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.10', '<'))
{
    die('Your host needs to use PHP 5.3.10 or higher to run this version of Joomla!');
}

define('_JEXEC', 1);

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php'))
{
    include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';
}


if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';


JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterLoad') : null;

$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

$app->execute();
?>
```

Here is my javascript code that I would like to add to joomla:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./send_resume/pmc_resume_js.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".carouselrow").html("");
    $(".messagerow").html("");
    $(".contentrow").html("<div class='row'><div class='col-lg-2'></div><div style='background-color:white' id='resume_forms' class='col-lg-9'></div><div class='col-lg-1'></div></div>");
    $("#resume_forms").load("./pmc_resume_forms.php","",""); 
    if($("#resume_forms").html()==""){
        $("#resume_forms").load(./pmc_resume_forms.php","",""); 
}
    $(".contentrow").css("background-color", "#F0F4F7"); 
    $(".breadcrumbs").html("<span class='showHere'>You are here: </span><span>Career</span></div>");
    $("title").html("Career");

});
</script>
```

When I don't add the jquery library at the beginning of tmy code, the bootstrap dropdown navbar doesn't work.

When I add the jquery file to the beginning of my code and don't add the jquery file at the beginning of my javascript code, the dropdown navbar worked properly but my javascript code did not work.

When I added jquery library file in the both place's, my javascript code works fine, but the navbar menu doesn't work.

How can I solve this? thanks...

Comment: Please don't make ANY core code changes to Joomla. Use a plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Joomla Docs:

**Bootstrap:**

> To enable the Bootstrap framework, call
>   JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework'). This will automatically enable the
>   jQuery framework in noConflict mode (i.e. accessed via jQuery. instead
>   of $.). The Bootstrap library included is version 2.1.0 and is located
>   at media/jui/bootstrap.js. It includes methods to initialize the
>   Bootstrap affix, alert, button, carousel, collapse, dropdown, modal,
>   tooltip, popover, scrollspy, tab and typeahead plugins.
>
> NOTE: There is a known incompatibility between bootstrap-button and
>   jquery-ui-button. Using both on the same page can result in conflicts.
>   See [1] for a possible workaround.

**jQuery:**

> In order to load jQuery, use JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
>
> This will load the jQuery version 1.11.1 library in no conflict mode.
>   This means it is accessed via the jQuery namespace, not through $.
>
> To load it in normal mode, call JHtml::_('jquery.framework', false);

**How to load JavaScript & CSS Files into Joomla:**

The proper Joomla way to load Javascript and CSS files would be `JHtml::script('path-to-file');` and `JHtml::stylesheet('path-to-stylesheet');`

Docpage: http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page

**Load a Script:**

> JHtml::script The following is the signature of this function, you can
>   see more at JHtml::script on api.joomla.org:
>
> script(string $file, boolean $framework = false, boolean $relative =
>   false, boolean $path_only = false, boolean $detect_browser = true,
>   boolean $detect_debug = true) : mixed

**An Example Script:**

```
<?php
JHtml::script(JUri::base() . 'templates/custom/js/sample.js', true);
?>
```

**Use a Plugin**

A good Joomla plugin to load jQuery is [jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jquery-easy)